# Is there any option that the Stack Overflow team can block any group of users from accessing the site?

Tags: support, stack-overflow

I am asking this question to the Stack Overflow team.

Until two months ago we were able to access the Stack Overflow site in our office. But one fine morning when I tried to access the site, it was not accessible. I checked out with our network team and finally they told us it's an issue with Stack Overflow. They may be blocking the employees of our company.

I just want to know: is there any option as such? Maybe the network team is not able to solve the issue and want to wash their hands from this. That's why they are telling like this (telling some stories).

Please let me know, so that I can tell them to make it ready.

Comment: What error, *exactly* are you getting?

Comment: Now i dont remember that, may be tomorrow i can copy the error and ask some of my friend to post it. because now i am out of my company network

Comment: They have some incoming traffic limits to prevent scrawlers and spammers (maybe ddos). It has zero chance that ordinary users could hit it.

Comment: @peterh-ReinstateMonica if you're behind a stupid company firewall and you have 100 co-workers all accessing the SE network I'm pretty sure the HA-Proxy will throttle the connections from the company firewall.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest email to team@stackoverflow.com.  I think it is reasonably likely that your company's IP has been blocked by SO based on either voting irregularities or usage patterns.  This could be especially true if you're coming through a proxy which makes it appear that all of the users in your company are from the same IP.

Answer (score 1):

If the command

```
$ telnet stackoverflow.com 80
Trying 69.59.196.211...
Connected to stackoverflow.com.
Escape character is '^]'.
get /
<html>
<head><title>400 Bad Request</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>400 Bad Request</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx</center>
</body>
</html>
Connection closed by foreign host.
```

doesn't work and gives an `ECONNREFUSED` or `EHOSTUNREACH` then it is your site, your ISP, or something in between, not StackOverflow.

Comment: do i need to type $ telnet stackoverflow.com 80
in the command prompt? Could you please tell me where should i type this and check?

Comment: Very OS limited, MSW. Odds are @Nimesh is using Windows, and unless he deliberately stayed with XP, he likely won't even have the windows flavor of telnet installed on his box.

Comment: I am using vista, but i can check that from some xp machine as well

Comment: we do have a proxy for our company, is it blocking? few or other sites like orkut, face book is blocked in our company and if i try to access that, it will take me to access denied block page. but for SO i am not getting anything, getting only page cannot be displayed error

Answer (score 0):

There is always the possibility that the SO team banned your work's ip address, but this is unlikely

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Actualy i am able to ping stackoverflow from my machine.Is there any way to check whether SO team has blocked our company?